# Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire, multipartform-data

Following the [Alamofire Documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#uploading-multipart-form-data) for multipart form data uploads the request should be something like this:

```
AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multiPart in
    multiPart.append(data!, withName: "file", fileName: logFileName, mimeType: "multipart/form-data")
}, to: url).responseDecodable(of: DecodableType.self) { response in
    debugPrint(response)
}
```

However when I try this myself, I get the error `Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred` on the first line `AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multiPart in`.

I have not yet found a solution for what the correct way to do this is. Any suggestions are appeciated.

Comment: Do you have a type named `DecodableType` or did you just copy the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can try uploading the request this way as well... :)

```
AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multiPart in
    multiPart.append(data!, withName: "file", fileName: logFileName, mimeType: "multipart/form-data")
}, to: url).response { response in
    debugPrint(response)
    guard let data = response.data, let model = try? JSONDecoder().decode(YourCustomResponse.self, from: data) else {
        return
    }
}
```